# htaccess 404 Stopped Working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I had a custom 404 error redirect page working just fine through htaccess. However, after adding new code to htaccess, it stopped working. What's causing the conflict and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I've tried putting the ErrorDocument line at the top of the page and it still doesn't work.

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Removes www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Redirects to extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^&\ ]+).php
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

#Redirect nonexistent files to a 404 page (not working)
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: put the errorDocument statement at the top of the file.

Comment: I tried that actually, it still doesn't work. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not about putting `ErrorDocument` in the top or in the bottom of your htaccess.

You have an infinite loop because of your rule (the one rewriting to `php` extension).
You need to check if it exists before rewriting it, otherwise you'll get a loop conflict between your rule and `ErrorDocument`.

You can replace your current code by this one

```
RewriteEngine On

#Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Hide php extension (only for existing files)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+)\.php(?:\s|\?) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

#Redirect to extensionless php urls (only if it exists)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

#Redirect nonexistent files to a 404 page
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Answer (score 0):

put the errorDocument statement at the top of the file. Above the RewriteEngine Statement.

This is the solution, however I can't tell you why the above htaccess code causes that to fail.

Comment: does the file /404.html exist?

Comment: put the statement above the rewrite engine statement, at the very top of the file

Comment: I personally find there is sometimes a minute or twos delay between uploading and URLs applying .htaccess files :-/

Comment: Yes, the 404.html exists. Also, when I remove all the other code, the 404 error redirect works right away. I'm making sure to refresh the pages every time I update htaccess too.